# Calling helper method in loop for iterations

Tags: c#

calling method in foreach loop like

`foreach (object ofr in DataHelper.GetOffers(id, object))`

is better 
or take this `DataHelper.GetOffers(id, object)` out and assign that to variable like `foreach (object ofr in variableObject)` which is the better way and which will perform better and why?

Thanks

Comment: Better in what respect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is better and both will perform the same.

It's a matter of personal style preference.

Comment: Thanks for info, i was also wondering.

Answer (score 1):

IL code will be optimized in both ways in the release. So, either way, it will be the same in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you are only calling `DataHelper.GetOffers(id, object)` once. Thus there are no performance implications either way.

When people talk about moving methods calls out from loops they mean the loop's inner scope or the loop's body. Because if it's a call that can be made only once, you are wasting time by doing it in every loop's repetition.